# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler util

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I execute my java project with spring v.3.1 , so i get following error:

```
Bean 'configParser'; nested exception is 

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/util]
Offending resource: class path resource [Services.xml]
Bean 'configParser'
```

My POM has following dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

And my Service.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="configParser" class="com.cc.mp.srv.core.parser.ConfigParser">
        <property name="file" >
            <util:constant static-field="com.cc.mp.srv.main.Main.FILE_NAME"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Why could not locate the utility schema? I insert the core dependency in the pom file. The version number are also the same. 
What needs Spring yet?

**EDIT**

```
Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
2015-01-31 18:56:11,553 DEBUG (main) [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd}
```

If the debug messages is output, then it can be recognized that various version number is used. Could be the reason? How can the numbers be defined?

I also use the maven-assembly-plugin to create a executable jar file.

Comment: can you try to remove the version number from the xsd import?

Comment: It is the same error message when I remove them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Schema `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd`,  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd` (and the one with the versions) come with `spring-beans-<version>.RELEASE.jar`

Add this jar to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

---

**The problem with maven-assembly-plugin:**

You wrote:

> I also use the maven-assembly-plugin to create a executable jar file.

Ah... I guess that the maven-assembly-plugin is the cause for that problem. This is because the schema resolution mechanism works this way: Spring provides the XSD files with there jars. Within the jar, in the folder `META-INF` is a file `schema.info`. This file contains a listing of all XSD fiels and there locations (in the jar) provided by this jar.

example: spring.schema of `spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar`

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
```

So and now you have different jars (`spring-beans`, `spring-tx`, `spring-aop`, `spring-context`...) , that all contains a `META-INF/spring.schemas` file, with different content. On the other hand you use `maven-assembly-plugin` to aggregate the content of all the jar files in a single one.

I guess you will have this problem with the `spring.handlers` file too.

It looks like you can configure the `maven-assembly-plugin` to merge this files. see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331222/280244) of [How can I merge resource files in a Maven assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607220/how-can-i-merge-resource-files-in-a-maven-assembly)

An alternative solution would using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin`

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.1</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>YOUR.MAIN.CLASS</mainClass>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

(or use the `maven-shade-pluging`)

Comment: I've added the changes, but there is the same error message.

Comment: I think the maven-assembly-plugin is the key

Comment: thank you, yes it was the problem, so i used the maven-shade-plugin. Here is the link to the tutorial page http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-only-one-executable-jar-file-with-all-required-jars-properties-and-resources/

Comment: Thank you. For me it works when using spring-boot-maven-plugin instead of maven-assembly-plugin

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue with the maven-shade-plugin. The solution in my case was covered by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584752/spring-3-namespacehandler-issues-with-maven-shade-plugin).

Basically you have to add an [AppendingTransformer](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer) to your maven-shade-plugin configuration in pom.xml. Add the 2 AppendingTransformer entries from below:

```
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/bin</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>myName</finalName>
    <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.foo.MyApp</mainClass>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
        </transformer>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
        </transformer>
    </transformers>
...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the spring jars have spring.schemas and spring.handlers (which take care of the namespace handling) files in their respective META-INFs. Those files will get overwritten by each other. You will need to use the shade plugin (instead of assembly) with ResourceTransformers. The two combined, will merge the file content of the same file name onto one file. An example of the plugin for spring use would be something like this: (obtained from the ResourceTransformer link above). The two combined, will merge the file content of the same file name onto one file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```